# Namespace for WCF REST JSON Service

Tags: json, rest, namespaces, wcf-rest

We are using restful services simply returns json string by serializing JSON.NET. It is best practices to add namespaces to data contract. But we are not using any data contract since we are using Data Table to fetch the data simple return as json string.

Can you help me whether this service needs any namespaces? if yes where and why?